# Php getting directory list but how to get last modifed date

Tags: php, html, ftp

Below is my php code which displays the list of files in my directory with file size

$myDirectory = opendir(".");

```
        // get each entry
        while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory)) {
            $dirArray[] = $entryName;
        }
        // close directory
        closedir($entryName);

        //  count elements in array
        $indexCount = count($dirArray);
        Print ("$indexCount files<br>\n");

        // sort 'em
        sort($dirArray);

        // print 'em
        print("<TABLE border=1 cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0 class=whitelinks>\n");
        print("<TR><TH>Filename</TH><th>Filetype</th><th>Filesize</th></TR>\n");
        // loop through the array of files and print them all
        for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
                if (substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1) != "."){ // don't list hidden files
                print("<TR><TD><a href=\"$dirArray[$index]\">$dirArray[$index]</a></td>");
                print("<td>");
                print(filetype($dirArray[$index]));
                print("</td>");
                print("<td>");
                print(filesize($dirArray[$index]));
                print("</td>");
                print("</TR>\n");
            }
        }
        print("</TABLE>\n");
```

But now i need to edit to this code so that i can also get "Last modified date" ,, is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out PHP's `filemtime()` function. It looks like it may be just what you're looking for.

"This function returns the time when the data blocks of a file were being written to, that is, the time when the content of the file was changed."

Note that the time will be returned as a [UNIX Timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_timestamp).

[More information available here.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php)

Comment: hmmm worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the code below the get the modified date of files in a particular folder

```
<?php
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('FOLDER_PATH') as $file) {
if($file->isDot()) continue;
    echo date('Y-m-d',filemtime($file->getPathName())) . '<br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.getmtime.php

Comment: Thanks rohit and jack for adding more info....